# Close Bootstrap offcanvas sidebar by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify Boostrap Offcanvas Template.

The working example is http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/:

It works perfect for me and the only thing I'd like to add is closing the sidebar menu by tapping/clicking outside of it (now it works only by clicking toggle button).

I would appreciate your help.

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
      </p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4--> 
      </div>
      <!--/row--> 
    </div>
    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a> </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas--> 
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-right {
   right: 0;
  }


  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -50%; /* 6 columns */
  }


  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 50%; /* 6 columns */
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%; /* 6 columns */
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).is('#sidebar') && !$(target).parents().is('#sidebar')) {
         $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('active')
    }
});
```